# How to change the output type?

Tags: zod

e.g. we use a [Flavor type](https://spin.atomicobject.com/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) `UserId`

```js
interface Flavoring<FlavorT> {
  _type?: FlavorT;
}
type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;

type UserId = Flavor<string, 'UserId'>;
```

and want the zod-type to use be `UserId` instead of string.

Using refine seems to work, but I hope, that there is a better way that can avoid the function call:

```js
const MySchema = z.object({
  id: z.string().refine((v): v is UserId => true),
});

type MySchemaType = z.infer<typeof MySchema>;

// type MySchemaType = {
//    id: string & Flavoring<"UserId">;
// }
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-p4dj2x?file=src%2Fzod-test.ts&terminal=dev)